# A geometric-like distribution: determination of the parameter

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose that $M > \mu > m \geq 0$ are all fixed integers and assume that ${\bf p} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ is a probability distribution with support on $\{m,m+1,\ldots,M\}$ given by $$p_n = 0 ~~\text{for all $n \notin \{m,m+1,\ldots,M\}$}, ~~~\text{and}~~ p_n = p_m\cdot r^{n-m} ~~\text{for all $m\leq n \leq M$}$$ where $r \in (0,1) \cup (1,\infty)$ is the parameter (which plays the role of the "common ratio" in the usual geometric distribution). Assume also that the geometric-like distribution ${\bf p}$ defined above has a mean value equal to $\mu$ (i.e, $\sum_{m\leq n\leq M} np_n = \mu$ and $\sum_{m\leq n\leq M} p_n = 1$). I am wondering if it is possible to have a explicit formula which allows us to determine the unknown $r$ (and hence $p_m$ as a by-product) from $\mu$, $m$ and $M$ (which are all pre-fixed) ? It seems that there is no standard name for such a distribution in literature and the closest name I have found so far is the "geometric distribution on a bounded domain".

---

**Remark**: The question is equivalent to the following problem: Given integers $M > \mu > m \geq 0$ and suppose that $$\mu \sum_{m\leq n\leq M} r^n = \sum_{m\leq n\leq M} nr^n \tag{1}\label{1}.$$ Is it possible to solve for $r \in (0,1)\cup (1,\infty)$ from \eqref{1} which gives us a formula for $r$ in terms of $m$, $\mu$ and $M$? Notice that in the special case where $m = 0$ and $M \to \infty$, it is quite easy to obtain $r = \frac{\mu}{1+\mu}$.

**Edit**: I realized that $r$ can be larger than $1$ if $\mu$ is very close to $M$ and be relative large compared to $m$. Say for instance, $m = 2$, $\mu = 9$ and $M = 10$.

Comment: Is $p_m$ also known?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. $p_m$ is not known. There are two conservations (the total probability mass and the mean value) with two unknowns ($p_m$ and $r$)

Answer (score 1):

In order to find $r$ and $p_m$ basically we'll use both facts you mentioned. First we'll need to normalize the probability mass function:
$$\sum_{n=m}^Mp_n=\sum_{n=m}^Mp_mr^{n-m}=p_m\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}r^n=p_m\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}}{1-r}\overset{!}{=}1\iff p_m=\frac{1-r}{1-r^{M-m+1}}\ (\ast)$$
At last, we'll find the closed form of its mean value in terms of the fixed and wanted parameters:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=m}^Mnp_n=p_m\sum_{n=m}^Mnr^{n-m}&=p_m\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}(n+m)r^n\\
&=p_m\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}nr^n+mp_m\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}r^n\\
&=rp_m\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}r^n=\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}}{1-r}\right)+m\\
&=rp_m\left(\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}}{(1-r)^2}-\frac{(M-m+1)r^{M-m}}{1-r}\right)+m\\
&\overset{(\ast)}{=}r\left(\frac{1}{1-r}-\frac{(M-m+1)r^{M-m}}{1-r^{M-m+1}}\right)+m\\
&=\frac{r}{1-r}+(M-m+1)\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}-1}{1-r^{M-m+1}}+m\\
&=\frac{r}{1-r}-\frac{M-m+1}{1-r^{M-m+1}}+M+1\overset{!}{=}\mu\\
\end{aligned}
$$
$$\iff (M-m+2)r-r^{M-m+2}+m-M-1=(\mu-M-1)(1-r)(1-r^{M-m+1})\\
\iff (M-\mu)r^{M-m+2}+(\mu-M-1)r^{M-m+1}+(\mu-m+1)r+m-\mu=0$$
Usually you'd solve this later equation computationally. Maybe you could've solved for $r$ in terms of $p_m$ in the first equation and do the same process, but still, the problem wouldn't become more simple. At last, notice it now also satisfies the limit you told me, namely, that when $M\to\infty$ and $m\to 0$ we get
$$r=\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have got a similar polynomial equation for $r$ as well. Do you think whether there is any chance that one can solve $r \in (0,1]$ explicitly? By the way, as a sanity check, when you send $M \to \infty$ in your equation for $r$ and set $m=0$, you should recover $r = \frac{\mu}{1+\mu}$, which suggests that the equation you end up with might be problematic

Comment: I see, I'm revising what I've done wrong. By the way, about the edit you made, wouldn't the normalization sum, $\sum_n p_mr^{n-m}$, diverge for $r>1$?

Comment: Hi, the sum is over a finite set (i.e., a finite sum) and hence will never blow up...

Comment: I see, it'd only blow up in that limit ($M\to \infty$, $m=0$). As for the final equation, we got the same only that you got those $r^m$ terms and I got them as though $m=0$. I'll do it again and try the other way too. I'll then study the equation's behaviour as to see whether it can be solved explicitly for $r\in(0,1]$.

Comment: Hi Joan, as was suggested in my previous modification of the original post, $r$ might be belong to $(1,\infty)$ as well (so as long as the equation has a unique root other than $1$ it will be fine).

Comment: @FeiCao seems like my equation is correct according to this post I made: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857891/whats-r-if-frac1-r1-rm-m1-sum-n-mmnrn-m-mu?noredirect=1#comment10354205_4857891

Comment: What I've noticed is that for $\mu\leq 0$ there are no roots at $r\in[0,\infty)$, where as for $\mu\geq 0$, there are at least 1 or 2 solutions depending on if $M-m$ is small or big, respectively. I also noticed that for $r\geq 0$, $p_m$ is always bound between $0$ and $1$. As a last resort, I suggest solving the final equation via perturbation theory around some point you think it is near some root.

Comment: Thank you! I think the final take-away is that analytic solution can not be hoped for...