# What's $r$ if $\frac{1-r}{1-r^{M-m+1}}\sum_{n=m}^{M}nr^{n-m}=\mu$?

Tags: probability-distributions, power-series

I've a mass probability function which I have to normalize and of which I know its mean/expected value $\mu$. It is defined as $p_n=kr^{n-m}$, with $\ n\in[m,M]\subseteq\mathbf N_0$.

Normalizing it yields this condition:
$$k\sum_{n=m}^Mr^{n-m}=k\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}}{1-r}\overset{!}{=}1\iff k=\frac{1-r}{1-r^{M-m+1}}$$
At last, now we can find $r$ using the mean value equation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=m}^Mnp_n=k\sum_{n=m}^Mnr^{n-m}&\overset{n-m\to n}{=}k\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}(n+m)r^n\\
&=k\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}nr^n+mk\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}r^n\\
&=rk\frac{\text d}{\text d r}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{M-m}r^n=\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}}{1-r}\right)+m\\
&=rk\left(\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}}{(1-r)^2}-\frac{(M-m+1)r^{M-m}}{1-r}\right)+m\\
&=r\left(\frac{1}{1-r}-\frac{(M-m+1)r^{M-m}}{1-r^{M-m+1}}\right)+m\\
&=\frac{r}{1-r}+(M-m+1)\frac{1-r^{M-m+1}-1}{1-r^{M-m+1}}+m\\
&=\frac{r}{1-r}-\frac{M-m+1}{1-r^{M-m+1}}+M+1\overset{!}{=}\mu\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Upon further simplyfying I'd get
$$(M-\mu)r^{M-m+2}+(\mu-M+1)r^{M-m+1}+(\mu-m+1)r+m-\mu=0,$$
which does not concur with what someone else got (it has some additional $r^m$ term). That's why I wanted to corroborate whether my result is wrong or not.

Comment: Check now if your doubt has been solved.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with $=\frac{r}{1-r}-\frac{M-m+1}{1-r^{M-m+1}}+M+1$, and I think the final equation should be $$(M-\mu)r^{M-m+2}+(\mu-M\color{red}{\bf-}1)r^{M-m+1}+(\mu-m+1)r+m-\mu=0.$$